# Can't modify key/value hash slice in list assignment at .\metro.pl line 31, near "$year;"

Tags: perl

I'm new in Perl. I can not understand why I can not assign year to the hash field in string

```
   %currentBook{year}=$year;
```

Full code here.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use Time::localtime; 

my $maxYear = Time::localtime->year+1;
my $year = $maxYear;
my %currentBook = (name=>"firstCurrentBook",
    author=>"NO",
    place=>"NO",
    year=>0);
my %maxBook = %currentBook;
my %minBook = %currentBook;
print "Choose action\n1 - Input book\n2 - Print min max year\n3 = exit\n->";
my $cond = <STDIN>;
while ($cond  != 3)
{
    if ($cond == 1){
        print "\nInput book name: ";
        $currentBook{name} = <STDIN>;
        print "\nInput author surname and initials: ";
        $currentBook{author} = <STDIN>;
        print "\nInput place: ";
        $currentBook{place} = <STDIN>;    
        do{
            print "\nInput year of book: ";
            $year = <STDIN>;
            chomp $year;
        } while  (!looks_like_number($year) || $year < 0 || $year > Time::localtime->year);
        %currentBook{year}=$year;
        if (%currentBook{year} > %maxBook{year}){
            %maxBook=%currentBook;
        }
        if (%currentBook{year} < %minBook{year}){
            %minBook=%currentBook;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hash values are scalars, so you need `$currentBook` instead of `%currentBook`

Comment: @Matt Jacob, Re "*Hash values are scalars, so [...]*", Not a good thing to teach! `*g` is a scalar. `@a[@i]` isn't an array. `%h{@k}` isn't a hash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've already got the answer [in a comment by toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212031/cant-modify-key-value-hash-slice-in-list-assignment-at-metro-pl-line-31-near#comment83405306_48212031), but I will elaborate why this happens.

```
my %books = ( year => 2017 );
%books{year} = 2018;
```

This code will throw the error you saw.

> Can't modify key/value hash slice in list assignment at
>   /home/simbabque/code/scratch.pl line 6313, near "2018;"
>   Execution of /home/simbabque/code/scratch.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

To make your program do what you intended, you need to use the `$` [*sigil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)), not the `%` *sigil*, because the value inside `$books{year}` is a scalar.

But why the error message?

Actually, `%books{year}` is a totally valid Perl expression.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %books = ( year => 2017 );
print Dumper %books{year};
```

This will print

```
$VAR1 = 'year';
$VAR2 = 2017;
```

The construct `%book{year}` is a so-called *hash slice*, and it returns a list of key/value pairs. You can also put in a list of keys, and get a list of both the keys and their values out. This is useful to quickly construct a sub hash.

```
my %timestamp = ( year => 2017, month => 12, day => 31, hour => 23, minute => 59 );
my %date = %timestamp{ 'year', 'month', 'day' };

print Dumper \%date;
```

The output of that is

```
$VAR1 = {
          'day' => 31,
          'month' => 12,
          'year' => 2017
        };
```

However, this kind of behavior does not allow you to assign to `%books{year}`. It simply does not make sense, because it returns a list of key/value pairs. That's why this construct is not what we call an [*lvalue*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#lvalue) in Perl, so it cannot be [on the left hand side of an assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation).